# Join query result of 2 different tables based on common column

Tags: postgresql

I want to join the result of two different queries from two different tables based on a common column (which is named differently in the two tables) but I cant seem to figure out the easy way to do it. I'm using psycopg2 on python 3.5.

From the first table, I need the Count of meetings. So I do:

```
SELECT   user_id,COUNT(1) as num
FROM     tasks
WHERE    created_at BETWEEN %s and %s
GROUP BY user_id """,(DAYS_AGO_7_CONFIG,YESTERDAY))
```

This gives me

```
UserID | Number
1      |  123
2      |  12
```

`UserID` is my mutual column. Now I made `userID` into a list by list comprehension, then I do:

```
SELECT id, given_name,family_name,email FROM users WHERE id in +str(userID))
```

and I get the `id`, `given_name`, `family_name`, and `email` fields from the second table.

Now I need to add the Number column into this result, which I'm doing by very inefficient non-DB means (pandas library in python)

I'm pretty sure this entire thing can be done in one query (perhaps with union?), but I cant seem to work it out.

Intended output:

```
id | given_name | family_name | email | Number
```

Comment: Please show what the output should look like, as that's not entirely clear from your description.

Comment: Added, but i was using a guest account hence now it's pending peer edit

Comment: Feel free to request an [account merge](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for your two accounts so that you can restore your full control over your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with:

```
SELECT   u.id, u.given_name, u.family_name, u.email, COUNT(1) as num
FROM     users u JOIN tasks t
          ON (u.id=t.user_id)
WHERE    t.created_at BETWEEN %s and %s
GROUP BY u.id, u.given_name, u.family_name, u.email, (DAYS_AGO_7_CONFIG,YESTERDAY))
```

To address the question in the comments, you can add a `HAVING` clause after `GROUP BY` to limit the results to those where `num` is greater than 5:

```
HAVING   COUNT(1)>5
```

Comment: THANK YOU! i would mark you correct, but i was using a guest account just now =/ The WHERE clause in the 3rd line was unneeded as the ON did that, but is there a way to filter based on the num being > 5? i get num does not exist

Comment: @Wboy Changed my answer.